# Grabbing data from one file and sending it to another file using awk

Tags: shell, awk, text, text-processing

I have a jupyter notebook running in a directory with a bunch of output files.
The directory has a bunch of `.out` files, and I want to run awk on them to extract some information from them.

This is the bash script that works, for the most part:

```
for file in *.out
do awk '/SCF TOTAL ENERGY/ {print $NF; exit}' $file >> data.txt
done
```

This grabs the SCF TOTAL ENERGY from each output file, prints them out, and throws them into `data.txt`.

However, that is not the only information I want from my output files.

Let's say I have another piece of information called "USEFUL".
I want to grab the number associated with "USEFUL" (also at the NF position), create a new column in `data.txt` and fill up that column with the `USEFUL` data.

I know that I can create a new column in `data.txt` using

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="  "} 
{print $0 OFS }' data.txt
```

However, I don't know how to extract information from one file, and send it to `data.txt`, and making a new column at the same time.

Input *file**s*** look like this:
first.out

```
SCF TOTAL ENERGY ----> 1234
lorem
ipsum
text
here
more 
text
USEFUL ---> 4567
```

second.out

```
CF TOTAL ENERGY ----> 4321
lorem
ipsum
text
here
more 
text
USEFUL ---> 7654
```

third.out:

```
CF TOTAL ENERGY ----> 5566
lorem
ipsum
text
here
more 
text
USEFUL ---> 8877
```

I want my `data.txt` or final data file to look like:

```
1234  4567   
4321  7654
5566  8877
```

Where the first column is SCF TOTAL ENERGY and the second column is USEFUL.

At the moment, I only have the first column. I want to create a code where I can keep extracting information from my input files and keep adding columns.

Any advice you have is appreciated!!

Comment: Thank you for adding your efforts in your question, could you please post samples of input and expected output in your question for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: okay, i will make the files soon. thank you @RavinderSingh13

Comment: I have added some additional information. hope it helps @RavinderSingh13

Comment: Thanks for adding samples. Could you please do let us know 
 how line `-512.327909892086  29`  is coming in output, sorry but its not clear.

Comment: oh, since i only have example of an input file, i posted example number in out put file. i can make the edit.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i have added more explanation, with some easier numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. We need not to use a `for` loop to go through all `.out` files you could read all `.out` files by `awk` program itself.

```
awk '/SCF TOTAL ENERGY/{scfVal=$NF;next} /USEFUL/{print scfVal,$NF;scfVal=""}' *.out
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                  ##Starting awk program from here.
/SCF TOTAL ENERGY/{    ##Checking condition if line has SCF TOTAL ENERGY then do following.
  scfVal=$NF           ##Setting scfVal value to last field of current line here.
  next                 ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/USEFUL/{              ##Checking if line contains USEFUL then do following.
  print scfVal,$NF     ##Printing scfVal and last field value here.
  scfVal=""            ##Nullify scfVal here.
}
' *.out                ##Passing all .out files to awk program from here.
```

***NOTE:*** In case you have only 1 set of `SCF TOTAL ENERGY` and `USEFUL` then add `nextfile` after `scfVal=""` line to process it faster here(it needs GNU `awk`).